# When can I safely use the new <main> element in HTML5?

Tags: html, semantic-markup, specifications

On the 16th December, a HTML5 extension specification for the `<main>` element was [submitted to the W3C under something called an editors draft](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/html-extensions/raw-file/tip/maincontent/index.html). The abstract is as follows:

> This specification is an extension to the HTML5 specification [HTML5].
>   It defines an element to be used for the identification of the main
>   content area of a document. All normative content in the HTML5
>   specification, unless specifically overridden by this specification,
>   is intended to be the basis for this specification.
>
> The main element formalises the common practice of identification of
>   the main content section of a document using the id values such as
>   'content' and 'main'. It also defines an HTML element that embodies
>   the semantics and function of the WAI-ARIA [ARIA] landmark role=main.

Example:

```
<!-- other content -->

<main>

  <h1>Apples</h1>
 <p>The apple is the pomaceous fruit of the apple tree.</p>

 <article>
 <h2>Red Delicious</h2>
  <p>These bright red apples are the most common found in many
  supermarkets.</p>
  <p>... </p>
  <p>... </p>
  </article>

  <article>
  <h2>Granny Smith</h2>
  <p>These juicy, green apples make a great filling for
  apple pies.</p>
  <p>... </p>
  <p>... </p>
  </article>

</main>

<!-- other content -->
```

It's got all the info in there and I feel I should start incorporating it into web pages. As far as I know now, the HTML5 spec is just progressive with new features been "bolted" on to the spec with no upgrade. I guess that means the browsers will start implementing it when they can - the question is, how long does this take and how do I know all browsers support it? Should I just build it like so for now and resort to a polyfill?

Comment: The document cited is a mistitled proposal, nothing more. (Mistitled because its author is not one of HTML5 editors.) There have been heavy discussions around the idea, but it would be wrong to treat `main` as part of HTML5 (which itself is work in progress, though now received Proposed Recommendation status : http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/).

Comment: As far as I know however, Steve Faulkner is a contributor and the idea is backed by the likes of Bruce Lawson - does this hold any bearing?

Comment: It is not mis-titled and not a proposal it is a W3C First Public Working Draft (FPWD) approved for publication if you care to get you facts straight Jukka you can findout more about extension specifications in Plan 2014 http://dev.w3.org/html5/decision-policy/html5-2014-plan.html#modularity. The main element has broad support among users developers and implementers. Before becoming a FPWD the likes of Apple, Microsoft, Mozilla and Opera (all members of the HTML WG) can object to publication (none did)>

Comment: @rickyduck note: A W3C editors draft is the copy of the spec with the latest edits in it. A W3C working draft is a published snapshot e.g.http://www.w3.org/TR/html-main-element/

Comment: Whether a feature makes it into HTML5 or not depends on whether there will be 2 interoperable implementations of the feature before the cut off date for HTML5 becoming a recommendation. Thus an HTML5 extension spec can be folded into HTML5 if it meets the criteria. main may meet this criteria and if so...

Comment: @Jukka, speaking of HTML5 editor's: Robin Berjon wrote an article on the W3C blog the other day where he talks about what is happening with HTML (including extension specs e.g main) http://www.w3.org/QA/2012/12/html5_smile_its_a_snapshot.html

Comment: @SteveFaulkner thanks for clearing some of that up. IIRC Ian Hickson wasn't with the idea of implementing the tag as he stated: `What would the element _mean_? If it’s just “the main content”, then that is what the element’s contents would mean even without the element, so really it means the element is meaningless. And in that case, <div> is perfect, since that’s what it is: a grouping element with no meaning.` (which I disagree with, but I guess this is irellevant after the WHATWG and w3c split ).

Comment: its not up to hixie to decide, implementers decide: implementation of <main> in firefox has been assigned https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=820508 so it looks like it is happening :-)

Comment: "On the 16th" - of what?

Comment: December 2012, updated question

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Support for `<main>` will be much like support for any other new container element introduced in HTML 5.

- New enough browsers will support it.
- Older browsers will let you style it so it is `display: block` and give you the visual effects of it
- Older versions of IE won't support it at all without a JavaScript shim (which will work in exactly the same way as the ones for all the other new container elements).

The "when" depends on what level of browser support you need and how willing you are to depend on a JS shim.

Comment: So essentially, I can actually use the `<main>` element now with the required fallbacks, with no implications whatsoever and then whenever the application is submitted it will be semantically more effective? Is there not a chance also, that the element itself won't be "bolted on" to the spec?

Comment: With the same provisos as any other new element, yes. The spec is still subject to change, anything could be removed.

Comment: The element is *not* (yet) part of the HTML5 draft (and still less the WHATWG “Living Standard”). But with the provisions presented in the answer, it can be used almost as safely as the `<dwim>` element, except that `<main>` *may* actually make its way to the spec and to browsers, possibly with a defined meaning, default rendering, and expected browser behavior that surprise you.

Comment: That would be the HTML 5.1 draft (http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/Overview.html) you mean? The main element spec has equal standing to any of the new features that appear in HTML 5.1 and whether it is in the WHATWG standard or not, is of little significance.

Comment: @SteveFaulkner, the document you cite here says: “It is inappropriate to cite this document as other than work in progress.” (Besides, as of now, it does not describe a `main` element but instead lists the main content under “Common idioms without dedicated elements”.)

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela thanks for reminding me - bug filed https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=20474

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela FYI <main> is being added to HTML5.1 http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2013Jan/0012.html

Comment: The problem is that it won't work in ie10. HTML5 Shiv v3.6.2 makes sure the <main> tag works as expected in ie8 and ie9, but not (yet) in ie10. See https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/issues/114

Comment: @lafeber `main { display: block; }` will solve that for IE9+.

Comment: @lafeber is it just the default CSS styling that's needed? According to canisuse.com http://caniuse.com/#feat=html5semantic it seems there are quite a few browsers missing that feature. My real practical concern being, if I don't need to support IE8, do I need the HTML5 Shiv?

Answer (score 11):

For now, I would be careful about usng it.

For the future of the proposal, what really matters is implementation in browsers. In particular, because `<main>` is a proposed block level element, it will require a change to the HTML5 parser implementation as well as giving it the default ARIA role of main.

Without the default ARIA role, there is no point to the element, although using it now in preparation for that is a reasonable approach.

The parser change does require a modicum of care though. Remember that the `</p>` tag is optional. Now suppose you decide that before your "main" content you want a paragraph of preamble. You could write:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
  <p> This is my page preamble ...
  <main>
    My main content ...
    <div>
       A story ...
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

If and when browsers implement the `<main>` element, the `<main>` tag will automatically close the `<p>` element and in the DOM, the `<p>` element and the `<main>` element will be siblings of one another. The `<div>` element and its content will be a child of the `<main>` element. i.e. The DOM will be:

```
HTML
 +--HEAD
 +--BODY
     +--P
     |  +--This is my page preamble ... 
     +--MAIN
         +--My main content ...
         +--DIV
             +--A story
```

However, right now in browsers, the `<main>` becomes a child element of the `<p>` element, and while "My main content ..." is a child of the `<main>` element, the `<div>` element is not. i.e. the DOM has this structure:

```
HTML
 +--HEAD
 +--BODY
     +--P
     |  +--This is my page preamble ...
     |  +--MAIN
     |      +--My main content ... 
     +--DIV
        +--A story
```

Now, of course, this is easily avoided by explicitly using a `</p>` tag, on the preamble paragraph, but it is a trap for the unwary.

Comment: Raised a very good point! Thanks for your input! Out of habit, personally I always use `</p>` but like you say, certainly a trap for the unwary.

Comment: Since what time did changing element's display property resulted in chage of HTML parsing rules? You want to say putting a `div` inside an `a` wold actually make the `a` be inside the `div` as well? http://jsfiddle.net/ufmnb/

Comment: @SpadarShut - It doesn't. When I say "block-level", I mean equivalent to the HTML4 DTD's `%block;` entity definition, not the CSS display property. HTML5 doesn't really have the same concept but `flow content elements that aren't also phrasing content elements` is kind of similar.

Answer (score 8):

The [HTML 5.1](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/) [main element](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/grouping-content.html#the-main-element) is now [implemented](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/140341) in Webkit. [Validation support](http://validator.w3.org/nu/) to follow shortly. Expect [Firefox implementation](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=820508) soonish.

Comment: expect they will implement reasonable soon

Comment: @SteveFaulkner - Kudos to you Steve. Is there any chance of an example being added to the 5.1 spec where the main element clearly isn't at the scooby-doo point? Maybe something like the sample in my answer?

Comment: @Alohci have added a bug https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=20730 will get to it.

Comment: <main> element just landed in mozilla-inbound land https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=820508#c36

Answer (score 2):

You can go ahead and use it, Chrome 26 and Firefox 21 already implemented it.

Just as with the introduction of many other new HTML5 elements, not all browsers recognise `<main>` or have preset styles for it. You’ll need to ensure it displays as a block level element in your CSS:

```
main {display:block;}
```

For the time being, you'll also need to use JavaScript to create the element for older versions of IE:

```
<script>document.createElement('main');</script>
```

Of course, if you use the [html5shiv](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv), `<main>` is now baked in directly.