# Getting Safari to recognize <main> HTML 5

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

It appears as though some fairly recent versions of Safari don't support the `<main>` HTML5 element. (I have tested Safari 5.1.9 on Snow Leopard, and mobile Safari running on IOS 4 thus far). Is there a way to get Safari to recognize the `<main>` element (like a shiv)?

I have thrown together some example code below. When viewed in an affected version of Safari the green `<main>` box does not appear, if I were to add more text it would flow outside of the `<main>` element as if it were not even there.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <main>
        <nav id="bar"></nav>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </main>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
main{
width:800px;
height:800px;
background-color:#0C0;
}

#bar{
width:300px;
height:400px;
float:left;
background-color:#09F;
}
```

Comment: Have you added the element to the document and added a default style for it? `<script>document.createElement('main');</script>` and `main {display:block;}`

Comment: @PeeHaa: `<script>document.createElement('main');</script>` should only be required for IE8 and earlier.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most browsers display unknown elements as if they were `display:inline` by default, so popping this CSS in somewhere should do it:

```
main {
    display: block;
}
```

E.g.

```
main {
    display: block;
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: #0C0;
}
```

- http://jsfiddle.net/PeF8u/ — green area not visible
- http://jsfiddle.net/PeF8u/1/ - green area visible

(I tested in Safari 6.0.5 on Mountain Lion.)

Sitepoint have a good write-up of the `<main>` element: http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-main-element/

There’s also a great Stack Overflow answer that describes in a general way how to get new HTML5 elements working (for some definition of “working”) in older browsers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13949253/20578

Comment: Wow Paul, thanks for the quick response! This fixes the issue, I can't believe I didn't do this (considering I had to tell many other HTML5 elements to display as blocks). I would delete this question out of sheer embarrassment, but I feel that it could help others, so I'll leave it alone. Thanks again!

Comment: @user2569147: you’re very welcome — 7 minutes is actually quite slow for Stack Overflow, especially for slam-dunk questions like this one (very well-asked, by the way). Yeah, it’s easy to forget — I always use [Eric Meyer’s CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) for my projects, but it doesn’t currently include `<main>`, so I would have forgotten too. I think you’re right that it might help others, definitely worth leaving there.

Comment: @AdonisSMU: what is normalize?

Comment: @AdonisSMU: gotcha. Does sound like you might need to regularly update such a thing, to deal with new browsers. I guess the same is true of a reset like the Eric Meyer one, because new HTML elements are added.